# Field of real numbers (-a)*b = a*(-b)

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let's consider the field of real numbers $\mathbb R$. How do we prove that $\forall a, b \in \mathbb R: (-a)*b = a*(-b)$ using only axioms. This is supposed to be equivalent to showing that $a*b + (-a)*b = 0$ and I am able to take it from here. How do I know that the two formulations are in fact equivalent?

Comment: $(-a)*b=(-1*a)*b$ use associative law $-1*(a*b)$ and rearrange the equation to the similar case that you wrote down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The multiplicative inverse $1$ exists
- It has an additive inverse $-1$ with $0=1+-1$
- Any number $a$ has an additive inverse $-a=-1 \times a$ since multiplication is distributive over addition and $0=0\times a=(1+-1)\times a = (1\times a) +(-1\times a) = a+-a$
- Since multiplication is associative and commutative you have $(-a)\times b = (-1 \times a)\times b = (a \times -1)\times b = a \times (-1\times b)=a \times (-b)$

Answer (score 1):

Using distrbutivity, we have $a*b+(-a) *b=(a+(-a)) *b=0*b$, so if we can show $0*b=0$ then we can deduce $-(a*b) =(-a) *b$. Using commutativity we then get $a*(-b)=(-b)*a=-(b*a) =-(a*b) =(-a) *b$. Do you know how to prove $0*b=b$?